# Angled brackets

Tags: statistics, notation

What does this notation mean:

$ {\langle \ln(q(x|y)) \rangle}_{p(x,y)}$

where $p(x,y)$ is joint distribution of input (x) and input (y)

I found that $ {\langle \ln(q(x|y)) \rangle}$ means average value of $ { \ln(q(x|y)) }$

But what does $p(x,y)$ stands for?